# Can someone explain to me how asyncio and regular time.sleep() works?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm making discord bot in python. I want it to move quickly mentioned user between two chanels and then return to channel that he was before. `mentioned_member` is member that i get from message mention, `channel_one` and `channel_two` are channels to move aruond and `channel_to_return` is assigned few lines earlier as users current voice channel. It works, but not as intended - user is being moved between two channels as I wanted, but last move to `channel_to_return` executes after few seconds. I think this is because moving is corutine and time.sleep is executed in normal, synchronus way. Could someone explain how this exactly works?

'''

```
for i in range(5):
    await mentioned_member.move_to(channel_one)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    await mentioned_member.move_to(channel_two)
    time.sleep(0.2)
await mentioned_member.move_to(channel_to_return)
```

'''

Comment: Note that you shouldn't be using `time.sleep()` in async functions because it blocks the whole event loop - durinmg the sleeps no asyncio coroutines can run nor can events be processed. You should `await asyncio.sleep(0.2)` instead.

Comment: I did await asyncio.sleep as You suggested and moves inside for loop now execute as i wanted, but last move (that after for loop) still executes after around 5s, not 0.2

Comment: Why did you expect it to execute after 0.2s? You have a `for` loop that executes 5 times and executes two 0.2s sleeps and two `move_to` operations **in each iteration**. The whole thing has to take longer than 0.2s, don't you agree?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't detailed how you don't understand this.  Yes, the final move can be executed in a few seconds.  `sleep` is synchronous.  `await` simply waits for the asynchronous call to return -- in short, it turns that asynchronous call into a normal synchronous one, as far as *this* level of execution is concerned.

You loop through this 5 times, executing a total of 10 `sleep` delays, 0.2 seconds each.  That's a 2-second delay built in.  Add in the execution times of your eleven `move_to` operations, and you have your total time for this block of code.

The delay in seconds is simply

```
10 * 0.2 + 11 * <delay of move_to>
```

Does that clear up your understanding?

Comment: Thank You, it made it a bit more clear. I replaced time.sleep() with asyncio.sleep() but it works the same. What should I do to execute each move every 0.2s?

Comment: Ummm .... that's a new question, and requires you to provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  This post shows nothing of your current functionality.